# Waiting time Epson T88V

Tags: ios, macos, printing, epson

PROBLEM:
How to print (multiple) receipts without any delay?

As far as I know, there are at least 3 options to print with a T88V on OSX or iOS device. Unfortunately, all 3 of those options has a flaw.

OPTION 1:
I've been playing around with the official OSX driver (latest version 1.2a) and have no problems printing with it. However, between every print command, there's 1 sec delay.

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    [self TMAppPrint];
}

- (OSStatus)TMAppPrint
{   
    TMTextView *textWindow = [[TMTextView alloc] init];
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];

    OSStatus err = noErr;

    err = [TMPrintSupport TMSetJobTicket:printInfo printerName:@"TM-T88V" documentSize:NSMakeSize(204.0, 841.8) resolution:@"180x180dpi" speed:@"1" blank:@"Off" paperCut:@"DocFeedCut" chashDrwr1:@"Off" chashDrwr2:@"Off" buzzerControl:@"Off" buzzerPattern:@"Internal" buzzerRepeat:@"1"];

    NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textWindow printInfo:printInfo];
    [printOperation setCanSpawnSeparateThread:YES];
    [printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
    [printOperation runOperation];

    return err;
}
```

OPTION 2:
Using the iOS SDK (latest version 1.3.0) I can also print without problems but it's even worse. After sending the print command, there will be 1 sec delay till it prints.

```
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender
{
    if (printer != nil)
    {
        errorStatus = EPOS_OC_SUCCESS;
        if (builder != nil)
        {
            int printStatus = EPOS_OC_SUCCESS;

            // create a print document
            printStatus = [builder addTextLang: EPOS_OC_LANG_EN];
            printStatus = [builder addTextSmooth: EPOS_OC_TRUE];
            printStatus = [builder addTextFont: EPOS_OC_FONT_A];
            printStatus = [builder addTextSize: 1 Height: 1];
            printStatus = [builder addTextStyle: EPOS_OC_FALSE Ul: EPOS_OC_FALSE Em: EPOS_OC_TRUE Color: EPOS_OC_PARAM_UNSPECIFIED];

            // specify the print data>
            printStatus = [builder addText: @"hello!\n"];
            printStatus = [builder addCut: EPOS_OC_CUT_FEED];

            // send data>
            errorStatus = [printer sendData:builder Timeout:1000 Status: &status];

            // end communication with the printer>
            errorStatus = [printer closePrinter];
        }
    }
}
```

OPTION 3:
The last option is using the ESC/POS commands. I managed to get it to print some basic lines but I still don't understand most of it. There's no delay in printing though.

```
- (IBAction)button3:(id)sender
{   
    printer = [[EposPrint alloc] init];
    errorStatus = [printer openPrinter:EPOS_OC_DEVTYPE_TCP DeviceName:@"192.168.1.168"];
    builder = [[EposBuilder alloc] initWithPrinterModel:@"TM-T88V" Lang:EPOS_OC_MODEL_ANK];
}
```

I already directly asked Epson about this, but they couldn't give me any answer except it's working as intended... Which means I have to dive into the ESC/POS commands and learn it or are there still other options?